# ionic http get to a local file gives http error code 0?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, http, ionic-framework

I'm building a map using leaflet, mapbox, and omnivore. I have a .kml file with a list of markers on it. The markers load fine on desktop using ionic serve, but not when I actually run it on a mobile device (I have tested both android/ios).

I know that omnivore loads this file using an xhr request, so I decided to test that myself:

```
test = function() {
      $http.get('/kml/file.kml').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('Success!: ' + status);
      })
        .error(function(data, status,headers,config) {
          alert('FAILURE!: ' + status);
        });
    }
```

I get 200 success on desktop, but when I run it on a mobile device using ionic view or build it for Android I get failure with error code 0.

I'm not sure why this is happening on mobile devices, I have `<access origin="*"/>` in my config.xml.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dont't know what version of Angular you are running, but `$http.success` and `$http.error` has been [deprecated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/docs/api/ng/service/$http) (since v.1.4.4 I think) and been replaced with success and error callback functions

```
$http.get('/kml/file.kml').then(
  function successCallback(response) {
     console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(error) {
     console.log(error);
});
```

Not sure if this is your problem, but try update your angular and/or change your code and see if this makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that success/error had been depreciated. I posted my solution above, thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out the solution. I had a leading slash in the url to the file which was being read correctly when ionic serve was putting the site up as a server, but when using on a mobile device ionic launches the app using the file:// protocol and the leading slash was causing conflicts.

tldr; removed the leading slash, all is well.